# How to rename file in Finder if new name already exists?

Tags: macos, finder, ventura

In Terminal, I can run

```
mv file1 file2
```

which will remove an existing `file2` and then rename `file1` to `file2`.

Renaming the files in Finder directly yields the error message

> The name ... with extension ... is already taken. Please choose a different name.

So how can I rename a file in Finder to a name already existing and have Finder remove the existing file during the process?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, this helped a lot!